# How to get values from the array list which is set as bean using setAttribute()?

Tags: jsp, servlets, struts-1

This is the code for setting array list using setAttribute

```
@Override
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        PrintWriter out;
        out = response.getWriter();
        dbc.openConnection();
        travelDetails = new java.util.ArrayList();
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        if ("OK".equals(session.getAttribute("login"))) {
            String sValue = String.valueOf(session.getAttribute("status"));
            String employeeId = String.valueOf(session.getAttribute("employeeId"));
            TravelSettlement ts = (TravelSettlement) form;
            TravelBean tBean;
            String travelId = "";
            travelId = ts.getCheckedValue()[0];
            session.setAttribute("travelSId", travelId);
            dateDetails = new java.util.ArrayList();
            travelId1 = new java.util.ArrayList();
            String query1 = "select td.travel_id,td.date,td.mode,td.travel_from,td.travel_to,td.purpose from travel_details td,travel_master tm where td.travel_id=tm.travel_id and td.travel_id='" + travelId + "'";
            ResultSet rs1 = dbc.processSelect(query1);
            while (rs1.next()) {
               String date = "";
               String mode = "";
               String travel_from = "";
               String travel_to = "";
               String purpose = "";
               tBean = new TravelBean();
               TravelBean tb1 = new TravelBean();
               long travel_Id = Long.valueOf(rs1.getString(1));
               tBean.setTravelId(travel_Id);
               Bean.setDate(DateUtil.stringToSQLDateFormat(rs1.getString(2), "yyyy-MM-dd", "dd-MM-yyyy"));
               tBean.setMode(rs1.getString(3));
               tBean.setTravelFrom(rs1.getString(4));
               tBean.setTravelTo(rs1.getString(5));
               tBean.setPurpose(rs1.getString(6));
               travelDetails.add(tBean);
               dateDetails.add(tBean);
               travelId1.add(travelId);
            }
            request.setAttribute("travelId", travelId1);
            request.setAttribute("dateDetails", dateDetails);
            session.setAttribute("travelDetails", travelDetails);
            return mapping.findForward("edit_request");
        } else {
        return mapping.findForward("error");
    }

}
```

And This is My My JSP code, where am accessing the bean array data

```
<html>
<body>
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" border="0" id="myTable">
    <script>
       var i = 0;
       var name="#tbodyId"+i;
    </script>
    <logic:iterate id="dateDetails" name="dateDetails">
       <tbody>
           <tr>
              <logic:lessThan property="date" name="dateDetails" value="2">
               <td width="14%" >
                 <html:text property="date" name="dateDetails" size="12" readonly="false" styleClass="hometext" />&nbsp;
                 <img src="./images/cal.gif" alt="calender" onclick="displayCalendar(document.forms[0].date[0], 'dd-mm-yyyy', this)"/>
               </td>
             </logic:lessThan>
             <logic:greaterEqual property="date" name="dateDetails" value="1">
              <td width="12%" >
                 <html:text property="date" name="dateDetails" size="12" readonly="false" styleClass="hometext" />&nbsp;
                 <img src="./images/cal.gif" alt="calender" onclick="displayCalendar(document.forms[0].date[i++], 'dd-mm-yyyy', this)"/>
              </td>
             </logic:greaterEqual>
               <td width="12%" class="tbldata" >
                 <html:select property="mode" styleClass="hometext" name="dateDetails">
                   <html:options name="modeOption" labelName="modeValue"/>
                 </html:select>
                </td>
                <td width="15%" class="tbldata" align="center"><html:text property="travelFrom" name="dateDetails"/></td>
                <td width="13%" class="tbldata" align="center"><html:text property="travelTo" name="dateDetails"/></td>
                <td class="tbldata">
                   <html:textarea property="purpose" name="dateDetails" rows="2" cols="20" styleClass="textarea" onchange="ajaxDateCheckValue()"/>
                </td>
                <td width="15%" class="tbldata" align="center">
                   <button type="button" onclick="setHidden()">Update</button>
                </td>
             </tr>
           </tbody>
        </logic:iterate>
     </table>
</body>
 </html>
```

I want to use that array to update the edited details by the user to the database and the array name is (dateDetails).

Comment: use [JSTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages_Standard_Tag_Library) in your JSP

Comment: Which Arraylist are we talking about?How are you handling updated attributes by user in current scenario?

Comment: @ShivamAggarwal dateDetails is an ArrayList, am setting the bean attributes into the while loop and am adding bean object to the ArrayList(dateDetails), you can see in the first section of the code, please help me with this, thank you...

Comment: Is  <logic:iterate a custom taglib,so r u correctly able to iterate arraylist thru this,if not u can use jstl taglib for the same <c:forEach items="${myList}" var="element"

Comment: yes it is iterating the ArrayList, and it is fetching all the elements in the ArrayList, but i need to update the edited details of the user to the database with the same ArrayList, since the elements in the ArrayList are dynamic, and ArrayList (i.e dateDetails) in not a bean class,or else i could have used getter method to get the elements.

Comment: @ShivamAggarwal please give me the suggestions and i want to use that ArrayList in .java file not in .jsp file

Comment: Judging from the used tags,which version of struts are u using?

Comment: @ShivamAggarwal am using struts 1.3.10. please suggest me about this, by long time am not able to fix this bug.